# How To: use Actionfilter to create thumbnail like HTTP Handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc

sorry for the lame question but with HTTP handler it is easy to do that, just intercept an image file and parameters and HTTP handler will do it for you like for example

the question is how you can do that with ActionFilter and let it intercept any image ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that with an ActionFilter though?

Comment: i dont know, i am new to MVC and thought it might be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An action filter only handles the current request, and only if that request is to an ASP.NET MVC controller. Images are all handled by distinct, separate requests. Even if you could identify which images are going to be requested by a request to a controller, you can't return multiple files in a single request. The only way to actually capture the requests to images themselves and generate thumbnails via get query would be a custom HttpHandler.